# Under touch-typing methodology, why is upper case "S" done via "right_shift + s"? Why can't I use "left_shitft" for this?

Tags: keyboard, touch-typing

I am trying to learn touch typing via this website called [typing.com](https://www.typing.com/student/lesson/323/shift-key-and-capitalization)
[image].

In the intermediate lessons, there are instructions on how to type upper case "S" which is suggested by using the "right_shift" and the letter "s".  But, the "left_shit" is closer to "s".

Why can't I use "left_shitft" with left pinky for this?

Obs.: not sure if Super User is the right forum for this question. There is already a tag for touch-typing. Hence, it seemed to be appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Touch typing one's never supposed to press two keys simultaneously with one hand. This is for

1. speed and accuracy. Just as an example, typing "Sandman" is
   faster and more accurate when the keypresses are split between
   hands.
2. preventing unnatural form of the hand. Fingers are always resting /
   hovering on the same keys, in a natural position, and certain key
   combos break the natural form. Breaking the form can lead to RSI.
3. conformity. When typing the alternative characters, the keypresses are always
   split, which makes it easier to remember. Non-splitting breaks the
   rule, consequently making recall more difficult.

That said, many if not most touch-typers actually do break the rules and type `S`,`I` or `(` with one hand only. Typing speed isn't really an issue except for professional typists.